# Numbers with two digits exceeds the cell in tabularx

Tags: margins, tabularx

I have the following code:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{makecell}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{multirow,multicol}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    %\usepackage{adjustbox}
    \usepackage{scalerel,amssymb}

    \setlength\parindent{0pt}

    \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

    \begin{document}
        \begin{table}[htbp]\centering
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|C|*{12}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.1cm}|}}
    \hline
               &                                                                                      \multicolumn{12}{c|}{Months}                                                                                      \\ \cline{2-13}
               & 1                & 2                & 3                & 4                & 5                & 6                & 7                & 8                & 9                &10               &11 &12                                                    \\ \hline
    Activity 1 & \cellcolor{gray} & \cellcolor{gray} & \cellcolor{gray} &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &    &                                                    \\ \hline
    Activity 2 &                  & \cellcolor{gray} & \cellcolor{gray} &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &    &                                                    \\ \hline
    Activity 3 &                  &                  & \cellcolor{gray} & \cellcolor{gray} & \cellcolor{gray} &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &    &                                 \\ \hline
    Activity 4 &                  &                  &                  &                  & \cellcolor{gray} & \cellcolor{gray} &                  &                  &                  &                  &    &                                                     \\ \hline
    Activity 4 &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  & \cellcolor{gray} & \cellcolor{gray} & \cellcolor{gray} &                  &    &                                    \\ \hline
    Activity 4 &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  & \cellcolor{gray} & \cellcolor{gray} &   \cellcolor{gray} &  \cellcolor{gray}  \\ \hline

    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Cronogram}
    \end{table}


\end{document}
```

It returns an warning saying "Overfull \hbox...". Any ideia to fix this?

Plus, is there a way to substitute "\cellcolor{gray}" for a command? Thanks!

Output table screenshot:
[image]

Comment: 1) increase the width widthin `m{...}`. 2) \newcommand{\mycell}{ \cellcolor{gray}} and then use `\mycell` instead of `\cellcolor{gray}`.

Comment: An alternative for 1): put a fixed width for the first colum and use `X` for all the month columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be under the impression that if one specifies the column type as `m{1mm}`, the column's width will be `1mm`. In fact, that's merely its *usable* width; its *full* width is `1mm+2\tabcolsep`; the length parameter `\tabcolsep` (default value: `6pt`) governs the amount of whitespace that's inserted to the left *and* right of each column. Since 72.27 TeX points = 1 inch, 1 TeX point is equal to about 0.3515mm, and the *total* width of each `m{1mm}` column is actually `1mm+12*0.3515mm=5.22mm`.

If the font is Computer Modern and the font size is `11pt`, the width of each and every numeral is `5.475pt`. Given that you've specified a *usable* column width of only `1mm=2.84pt`, it's not surprising that you get lots of warning messages about overfull boxes and that the two-digit numbers protrude into the following cells.

I take it that (a) you'd like to keep the month columns as narrow as possible and also (b) all 12 month columns should be equally wide. If that's the case, I suggest you take the following approach: Set `\tabcolsep` to a very small value, say, `0.5pt`, and set the usable width of each month column to the width of the widest material in the header cells -- here, the number `12`. The width of the number `12` is 2*5.475pt=10.95pt; the total width of the cell will be `10.95pt+2*0.5pt=11.95pt=4.2mm` -- about 1mm *less* than in your initial setup. Keep using a `tabularx` environment to maximize the usable width of the first column.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
% I've simplified and streamlined the preamble
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

% Some new code
\newlength\mylength
\settowidth\mylength{12} 
\newcommand\cg{\cellcolor{gray}} % handy shortcut macro


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp] 
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|C|
 *{12}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.1cm}|}}
 \hline
 & \multicolumn{12}{c|}{Months} \\ 
 \cline{2-13}
 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 &10 &11 &12 \\ 
 \hline
 Activity 1 & \cellcolor{gray} & \cellcolor{gray} & \cellcolor{gray} & & & & & & & & & \\ 
 \hline
 Activity 2 & & \cellcolor{gray} & \cellcolor{gray} & & & & & & & & & \\ 
 \hline
 Activity 3 & & & \cellcolor{gray} & \cellcolor{gray} & \cellcolor{gray} & & & & & & & \\ 
 \hline
 Activity 4 & & & & & \cellcolor{gray} & \cellcolor{gray} & & & & & &\\ 
 \hline
 Activity 4 & & & & & & & \cellcolor{gray} & \cellcolor{gray} & \cellcolor{gray} & & & \\ 
 \hline
 Activity 4 & & & & & & & & & \cellcolor{gray} & \cellcolor{gray} & \cellcolor{gray} & \cellcolor{gray} \\ 
 \hline
 \end{tabularx}
\caption{Original form}
\end{table}

\setlength\tabcolsep{0.5pt} %default is 6pt

\begin{table}[htbp] 
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|C|
 *{12}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\mylength}|}}
 \hline
 & \multicolumn{12}{c|}{Months} \\ 
 \cline{2-13}
 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 &10 &11 &12 \\ 
 \hline
 Activity 1 & \cg & \cg & \cg & & & & & & & & & \\ 
 \hline
 Activity 2 & & \cg & \cg & & & & & & & & & \\ 
 \hline
 Activity 3 & & & \cg & \cg & \cg & & & & & & & \\ 
 \hline
 Activity 4 & & & & & \cg & \cg & & & & & &\\ 
 \hline
 Activity 4 & & & & & & & \cg & \cg & \cg & & & \\ 
 \hline
 Activity 4 & & & & & & & & & \cg & \cg & \cg & \cg \\ 
 \hline
 \end{tabularx}
\caption{Modified form}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mean, not exactly 1mm column wide, but 1mm in the specification m{1mm}. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 5):

Instead of fixing the column width of the 12 final columns, set the content in regular `c`entred (non-fixed-width) column. And then use [`collcell`](//ctan.org/pkg/collcell) to capture the content of the columns and set them in a box that naturally fits to the widest element. This latter max-width-box-fixing is done using [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox)'s `\eqmakebox[<tag>]{<stuff>}`. Elements using the same `<tag>` are set in a box of the same, naturally-widest, box.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx,collcell,eqparbox}

\newcommand{\fixwidth}[1]{\eqmakebox[colhead]{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\collectcell\fixwidth}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcommand{\graycell}{\cellcolor{gray}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ | >{\centering\arraybackslash}X | *{12}{C|} }
    \hline
               &                                                                                      \multicolumn{12}{c|}{Months}                                                                                      \\ \cline{2-13}
               & 1                & 2                & 3                & 4                & 5                & 6                & 7                & 8                & 9                &10               &11 &12                                                    \\ \hline
    Activity 1 & \graycell & \graycell & \graycell &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &    &                                                    \\ \hline
    Activity 2 &                  & \graycell & \graycell &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &    &                                                    \\ \hline
    Activity 3 &                  &                  & \graycell & \graycell & \graycell &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &    &                                 \\ \hline
    Activity 4 &                  &                  &                  &                  & \graycell & \graycell &                  &                  &                  &                  &    &                                                     \\ \hline
    Activity 4 &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  & \graycell & \graycell & \graycell &                  &    &                                    \\ \hline
    Activity 4 &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  & \graycell & \graycell &   \graycell &  \graycell  \\ \hline
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{Cronogram}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

If you want multiple such tables that have varying fixed-width, one can also achieve this using manual insertion of `\eqmakebox` with an appropriate table-specific `<tag>`.

---

If you truly want the columns to be `0.1cm` (or `1mm`), you can use the following definitions in your preamble:

```
\newcommand{\fixwidth}{\makebox[0pt]}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\collectcell\fixwidth}p{1mm}<{\endcollectcell}}
```

[image]

No need to use `eqparbox` then.

Comment: Thanks for answering! That'll do, but I want those cells to be 0.1cm wide.

Comment: @User01 how can you get any readable text into a column that is .1cm wide? at the default font size that is just enough space to typeset a single `.`

Comment: @User01: See the updated answer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I guess it's a Gantt chart, which doesn't really take content other than colouring.

Comment: @Werner well it has two digit heading as shown. Fitting "10" into 1mm column is going to take a rather small font.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - not exactly a 1mm column wide, but m{1mm}. It's just a Gantt chart like Werner said, so it doesn't need space for texting other than numbers

Comment: @User01 `m{1mm}` is a `\parbox{1mm}` it allocates _exactly_ 1mm for the column content anything wider than that will generate overfull box warnings and misaligned output.